# Killing a pthread waiting on a condition variable

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have a pthread waiting on a condition variable using `pthread_cond_wait()`.  It's waiting for data from a queue structure that is filled by another thread.  I want to kill this thread, preferably without `pthread_kill()`.

On Linux and WinPthreads doing a

```
pthread_cancel();
pthread_join()
```

is enough to kill it.

However, on OS X it hangs on the `pthread_join()` call. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm using SDL so perhaps that is confounding the problem.  I know SDL provides it's own thread implementation, and perhaps I should use it because pthread/SDL have some bizarre interactions, but I have quite a  bit of pthread code written already and I would prefer to keep it that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have access to the queue, and control of the object schema for enqueued items?  If so, define a queue object type that when de-queued, instructs the thread that is processing the item to exit gracefully.

Now, to shut down these threads, simply post a number of these "quit" objects to the **HEAD** of the queue that corresponds to the number of threads that are servicing the queue, and join on the threads.

This seems much cleaner than the "nuclear option" of pthread_cancel/kill.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I did!  Thanks for the suggestion, this way my thread can still remain in the dark and run in non threaded instances and my queue which is already thread aware can take care of the dirty work and call pthread_exit to kill the thread.

Answer (score 7):

`pthread_cancel` should wake a thread that is blocked in `pthread_cond_wait` --- this is one of the required cancellation points. If it doesn't work then something is wrong.

The first thing to check is that cancellation is indeed enabled on the target thread --- explicitly call `pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE,&oldstate)` on the target thread to make sure. If that doesn't work, then cancellation is broken on your platform and you'll have to resort to alternatives such as setting a "please stop now" flag and signalling the condition variable.

**Do not** use asynchronous cancellation unless you **really** know what you are doing --- it can trigger the cancellation in the middle of any operation (e.g. in the middle of setting up a function call stack frame or running a destructor), and thus can leave your code in a thoroughly inconsistent state. Writing async-cancel-safe code is **hard**.

Incidentally `pthread_kill` does **not** kill a thread --- it sends a signal to it.

Comment: I did pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, &oldstate).  The old state was PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE and this had no effect.  I'd be very surprised if Mac OS X's pthreads was broken, but I'm not sure what else could be wrong, as this code works on both windows and linux.

Comment: pthreads works fine, I wrote a little program:
pthread_cond_t  cond;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void* tmain(void *)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, tmain, NULL);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_cancel(thread);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
}

To test it and it exits after a second.  I must have some other bug in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try would be to kick the condition variable in between the cancel and the join, and have your target thread check for cancellation explicitly after it returns from the condition wait.

That's because it may be that the thread is not responding to cancellation while it's in the condition wait (or at all).

POSIX.1c-2004 (v6) states:

> The cancelability state and type of any newly created threads, including the thread in which main() was first invoked, shall be `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE` and `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED` respectively.

That means you have to explicitly check for cancellation with `pthread_testcancel()`.

The other option is to actually set the threads cancel type to `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS` when it first starts to run, something like:

```
int junk;
pthread_setcanceltype (PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, &junk);
std::cout
    << ((junk==PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED) ? "Was deferred" : "Wasn't")
    << std::endl;
```

That is, of course, assuming that's what the problem is. You should be able to test if it is by examining the output of that third line above.

Cancellation is a *request* to the target thread which it is free to ignore if it wishes, as opposed to the far more evil `pthread_kill()`. I'm a great believer in letting threads control their own lifetimes since I've found it invariably leads to fewer concurrency problems.

> *Aside:* In fact, having been bought up in very early editions of pthreads, even before integration into DCE, I *still* find myself just using a global variable for each thread indicating when it should exit, along with manually kicking mutexes or condition variables to wake the threads up. I guess I should update my methods (or I would if I could see a clear advantage). :-)

Comment: Well, I would definitely prefer to have some non-cancel method but I have but the thread that gets cancel isn't actually aware that it's running in a thread.

I have tried signalling the condition variable, but it then reads from the queue and segfaults because there is nothing in it.  While this has the desired behavior of exiting the program, it seems 'just wrong.'

Comment: BTW, you should never assume that, just because you return from cond_wait, there is work available. It's possible for two threads waiting to be woken, the first to get the work and the second should detect no work available and go back to wait.

Comment: Deferred cancellation state does not mean you have to explicitly check for cancellation with `pthread_testcancel()`; this function is just one of many cancellation points POSIX defines. You pretty much *never* want asynchronous cancellation except when performing long numeric computations with *no* library calls whatsoever. The only library call you can make while asynchronous cancellation is enabled is to disable asynchronous cancellation. :-)